# Casting with #if in C

Tags: c, casting, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

Why this code gives an error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Rep (int)6
int main(){
     #if Rep==6
         printf("T");
     #else
         printf("F");

     #endif

return 0;
}
```

1. Why does it refuse the casting?
2. Is it a 'preprocessor error' or a 'compiler error'?

Comment: Can you  post the error?

Comment: The error you're probably seeing is because the preprocessor doesn't understand either the type name `int` or the cast operator. The errors or warnings that you're not seeing, or are just ignoring, are because (a) you're missing the required `#include <stdio.h>`, (b) `void main()` should be `int main(void)`, and (c) output should be terminated with a newline: `printf("T\n");`.  Compilers aren't required to diagnose all of these problems, but you definitely should fix them.

Comment: @nielsbot 
the error from Eclipse IDE :"missing binary operator before token "6"  "

Comment: @MinaSamir, this is actually an excellent hit from Eclipse, please see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a preprocessor error. It happens because the preprocessor does not understand how to cast a variable. You cannot use any C code with `#if`, just simple numbers, or macros which expand to a number.

If you cannot modify `Rep`, you can work around this with a helper macro, which removes the casting from the beginning:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define X(x)
#define Y(x) X x
#define Rep (int)6

int main(void) {
#if Y(Rep) == 6
    printf("%d\n", Y(Rep)); // prints 6
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is a devious little macro.

Comment: Just simply `#define Rep ((int)+6)` would do. But wait, `6` is an `int`, so why the cast all together.

Comment: @JensGustedt I don't agree that's simpler, because it differs from the typical cast syntax. That means you must modify the constant to add the hack. And if you can modify the constant, wouldn't a better idea be to remove the cast that has no effect?

Comment: Here is a real-world example, in which you cannot modify the constant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406246/remove-cast-from-constant-in-preprocessor

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen sure that there are cases where you don't control the macro. But if you do, you should do it like I describe in my answer. First, avoid the cast completely if literals of the type in question exist, and then use the `+` trick instead of relying on yet another macro.

Answer (score 2):

Preprossor macros that combine casts and that still should work in `#if` are easy to write: you just add a little `+` before the number. In your case

```
#define Rep ((int)+6)
```

The preprocessor replaces identifiers that it doesn't know by `0` so the end result is the same value.

But also, the cast in your `Rep` macro by itself is quite useless. `6` is an `int`, anyhow. So better avoid a cast for all integer types that have their own literals, combinations of `U` and `L` as suffix should do in most cases.